# How to get other field values in Laravel custom validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am using a custom validation rule to validate some data that I read from a file. The rule is as follows :

```
$this->rules = [
            'file_data'          => 'required|array',
            'file_data.*.id'     => 'required',
            'file_data.*.name'   => 'required',
            'file_data.*.code'   => 'required|code_exists' 
        ];
```

and apply these rules like

```
$validationResult = validator($data, $this->rules, $customMessageArray);
```

In the `code_exists`, I need the value of `id` for running a validation. I am trying to pass the value through `$parameters`, like `code_exists:id`, but it is giving me the string `id` in the parameter array. How can I pass the actual value ?

Comment: What are u doing in code_exists rule? Maybe we can find better solution.

Comment: I am checking whether the code exists in database for the ID. That is why I need the ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get key of array and after get the id. Like that:

```
'file_data.*.code' => [
    'required',
    function($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($data) {
        $index = explode('.', $attribute)[1];
        $id = data_get($data, "file_data.$index.id");

        $isExists = DB::table('table_name')->whereId($id)->whereCode($value)->exists();
        if (!$isExists) {
            return $fail(__('validation.exists', ['attribute' => $attribute]));
        }
   }
],
```

Comment: It is giving me an error which says `Undefined variable: data`

Comment: sorry i missed, you should put `use` keyword to function. change with that: `function($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($data) {` answer updated.